# How to open a new page when row is clicked in a JSF page?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF `h:datatable` with rows of data:

```
  <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
                    <!-- Check box -->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Select" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[dataItem.id]}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="№" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="№" value="№" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + SessionsController.firstRow + 1}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

I want to give to the user ability to open a new page when he clicks on a row.
I found that JavaScript code to be useful:

```
   $("table#dataTable tbody tr").click(function () {
            window.location = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href");
        });
```

The problem is that I need a JSF tag which will be used by JavaScript to open new page when the row is clicked and pass data. In this example href is used to navigate to the new window. I need JSF tag which can be used for the same purpose. Is there suitable JSF tag?

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use plain HTML `<a>` in JSF.

```html
<a href="page.xhtml">link</a>
```

Or `<h:link>`

```html
<h:link value="link" outcome="page" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, as to your jQuery selector, don't forget to take into account that JSF prepends the client ID with the ID of parent naming container components. Check the generated HTML output to be sure.

Comment: Is there alternative way to open a new page? For example is it possible when I click on a row to call a Java method from a managed bean. The Java method will return for example "123acb". I will configure this in a faces-config.xml as a navigation rule.

Comment: Not without a good load of JavaScript. It's easier to use for example PrimeFaces' `<p:dataTable>`. See also http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf

Comment: well, I prefer to use pure JSF. Can you think of any possible way to achieve my goal?

Comment: yes, but I have spent a lot of time to implement the JSF page, I don't want to start over again. Is it possible to use this tag <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowUnselect}" update=":form:growl"/>  insight my code?

Comment: You'd need to write some JS code for this yourself like as you already did with jQuery. You could submit hidden forms by JS/jQuery to invoke a bean action method.